# Guidance on setting Android version in AndroidManifest.xml/properties.project

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm working on a hybrid worklight application and need to set the minSdkVersion in the AndroidManifest.xml and target in the project.properties to android 10.  I've seen several references to manually updating these files, but I'm concerned that after modifying and checking into source control that they could be missing something (if they're generated again by Worklight).  Are there any configuration parameters in Worklight studio or other files to set the Android version or will it be ok to modify/check into source control and use the same file each time?

Comment: JJ Johnson, if your question is answered please mark it as Answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading this article, [Integrating with source control systems](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/r_integrating_with_source_contro.html), it looks to me like there will be no problem with committing the mentioned files into your source control application.

In Android (and Worklight), you set the minSdkVersion in Android's provided AndroidManifest.xml.